# C# Interface Downcasting

Tags: c#, interface, casting

First, I am very new to stack overflow and also C# programming..

Currently trying to make a program using some device with C#,
but there are some question which I don't understand in their SDK Example Code regarding usage of interface..

Here are the Interfaces in DLL:

```
interface ICanChannel2 : ICanSocket2, IBalResource, IDisposable
{
 blah blah
}

interface ICanSocket2 : IBalResource, IDisposable
{
 blah blah
}

interface IBalResource : IDisposable
{
  blah blah
}
```

I can't actually see the contents in interface but only their names.
and here is how it is used:

```
ICanChannel2 mCanChn = bal.OpenSocket() as ICanChannel2;
// (note that the return type of bal.openSocket() is IBalResource.)
```

This case is like casting IBalResource to ICanChannel2.

ICanChannel2 has been inherited from IBalResource , ICanSocket2 and IDisposable.

Can IBalResource, which is one of a base interface of ICanChannel2, be casted
to ICanChannel2?

Shouldn't ICanChannel2 have ICanSocket2 either? which IBalResource doesn't have?

BTW Code works and my brain stops..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not entirely clear what you're asking here. "Can X be cast to Y" - have you tried? What happens? Why does this not match your expectation?

Comment: any class implementing the interface `ICanChannel2` needs to also implement all methods from `ICanSocket2, IBalResource, IDisposable`  - while bal.OpenSocket()  retuns a IBalResource nobody forbids the implementation of `bal.OpenSocket()` to actually return a something that fullfills more then IBalResource - it mus at least return an IBalResource. If it returns some `ICanChannel2` implementation, you can do `ICanChannel2 mCanChn = bal.OpenSocket() as ICanChannel2;`, else it would be null.

Comment: Perhaps one thing to note is that you are not casting `IBalResource` to `ICanChannel2`, you are casting the _object_ returned by `bal.OpenSocket()` to `ICanChannel2`. That object can be of any class that implements `IBalResource`, and may be of a class that implements `ICanChannel2`. Note that objects belong to (are) a class and implement one or more interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, if you are using the `as` operator the instruction will always be successful but the result will differ. It will cast your object, if it's possible if not it returns `null`.

At the moment, when you call `bal.OpenSocket()`, the method returns an object which inherits the interface `IBalResource`. You have 3 interface definitions here, who all can be cast all the time to `IBalResource`.

So it is ok four your method `OpenSocket()` to return any object which inherits `IBalResource`, `ICanSocket2` and `ICanChannel2` since they all contain the methods defined in `IBalResource`

> Can IBalResource, which is one of a base interface of ICanChannel2, be casted to ICanChannel2?

`IBalResource` can be casted to `ICanChannel2` if the object you want to cast, inherits the interface `ICanChannel2` of course. But this is by far not granted! For example you can have one of the following:

```
class Bal : IBalResource {...}

class Channel : ICanChannel2 {...}

...

//Assignment is ok, since Bal inherits from IBalResource
IBalResource balResource = new Bal(); 
//Assignment is ok, since Channel inherits from ICanChannel2 and ICanChannel2 from IBalResource
IBalResource channelResource = new Channel(); 

balResource == typeof(ICanChannel2); //false
channelResource == typeof(ICanChannel2); //true
```

> Shouldn't ICanChannel2 have ICanSocket2 either? which IBalResource doesn't have?

Yes, the `ICanChannel2` will have the methods of `ICanSocket2` but also the methods of `IBalResource`.

Hope this clears things up. Maybe you want to read up on inheritance again.

Btw. you can omit many redefinitions in the interface defintions.

```
interface ICanSocket2 : IBalResource, IDisposable
```

is the same as

```
interface ICanSocket2 : IBalResource
```

Comment: Thank you all guys! :))) 
@Thomas Thank you so much for your answer! 
One more thing I want to ask : "`IBalResource` can be casted to `ICanChannel2` if the object you want to cast, inherits the interface `ICanChannel2` of course."   `IBalResource` which I want to cast, doesn't inherit the interface `ICanChannel2` but `ICanChannel2` Inherits `IBalResource` .. Then `ICanChannel2` can be casted to `IBalResource` since `ICanChannel2` inherits `IBalResource`, understood,, but `IBalResource` cannot be casted to `ICanChannel2` since `IBalResource` doesn't inherit `ICanChannel2`?

Comment: @IkheeJo It always depends on the concrete object which has been created somewhere down your code. If you have an object, which solely inherits from IBalResource it can't be cast to ICanChannel2 because it doesn't match all interface criteria. You can imagine it like interpreting an engine as a car. This won't work because the whole body of the car is missing. But interpreting the car as an engine is ok, since there is one built in.  Maybe this code fragment will help you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cA7HNE

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I think I am getting it. You are the best! :))

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have been digging the example source, and I think all the interface inheritance chain starts at the point its instance is constructed although I can't see the context. and there the instance inherits all the interfaces. Since the instance inherits all the interface , `ICanSocket`, `ICanChannel`, `IBalResource` and so on, the casting from one to another interface can be done.. Do you think I am getting close to it?

Comment: @IkheeJo Yes, you are on the right path. It all has to do with the instance of the object which is constructed. If you have a class which inherits an interface, the class has to implement every method of the interface. So the interface is a part of the class. If you have an interface which also inherits from another interface, the same is happening. In your example you have the `IBalResource` which inherits from `IDisposable`. So every class which will inherit from `IBalResource` will have to implement everything from `IBalResource` and `IDisposable`.

Comment: I can't thank you enough Thomas, you have been a great help! Bless you and Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ISon : IFather
interface ISonB : IFather

public IFather DoSome ( ISon son)
{
    //blah blah...
    IFahter fa = son;// here can cast "automatically" , because "ISon : IFather"
    return fa;
}

ISon son1;
IFather fa = DoSome(son1);
ISon son2 = fa as ISon; // here cast it back. not get a null.
ISonB son3 = fa as ISonB; //here get null, beacause son1 is not a ISonB
```